# Referencing common module from other modules in Android app

Tags: java, android, gradle, module, dependencies

I am creating a two-modules Android app.

One module is the normal tablet/phone module, another is the WearOS module.

But there is a third module called "common". The common module is compiled without errors. It has java classes, resources and so on. It has

```
import static com.myapp.common.R.*;
```

in the main java class, where the resources are needed (the IDE suggested to add that when red lines where under reference instructions for resources).

The three package names are similar to:

```
com.myapp.common

com.myapp.wear_module

com.myapp.phone_tablet_module
```

The app build.gradle file includes

```
implementation project(':app:common')
```

the wear module build.gradle file includes

```
 implementation project(':app:common')
```

the phone/tablet module includes

```
 implementation project(':app:common')
```

But I see that the resources and java files of the common modules are not referenced in the other modules. Furthermore I see a strange complaint like:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app:common
```

The IDE suggests to add the implementation line but it is already there. If I accept, it adds another one.

What is the problem. How to import the common module into the others?

Comment: try this `implementation project(':common')` , I think this is the issue

Comment: @Mohammed Alaa If I do as you say I get an error "Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':common' could not be found in project ':app'"

Answer (score 0):

try this `implementation project(':common')`

then in **settings.gradle** make sure that common module are included like this

```
include ':app', ':common', ':wear_module', ':phone_tablet_module' // as this is the modules names
rootProject.name='MyApp'
```

Comment: It is the same, the reference is not available.

Comment: can you share the content of your **settings.gradle** file and a screen shoot of your project overview

Comment: settings.gradle contains the line you suggested and before it two lines: include ':app'
rootProject.name='MyApp'

Comment: @P5music did the edited answer helped you to solve the issue ?

Comment: The issue is now solved but I do not think it is due to your answer so I cannot mislead the other users by accepting it. It is not clear what solved the issue.